# How can I compare files when I push the changes, but forget change the nuspec version?

Tags: nuget, push, nuspec

I have a build pipeline that I send nuspec files for packing. On the push job, I enabled it to overwrite the same version, to avoid a 409 error.

If I change the code, or do some changes, but forget to change the version of nuspec, is there a way or function to compare files before starting the build?